# Loading JSON data into Elasticsearch and Kibana using logstash configuration [ConfigurationError: translation missing]

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am trying to import some JSON data into my Elasticsearch and Kibana cluster using logstash and its configuration. I am using a JSON file having three fields.

```
elasticsearch version used: 6.5.3
logstash version used: 6.5.3
```

Logstash version used: 6.5.3

Sample JSON file: test.json

```
{"name":"Jonathan","score":"9.9","address":"New Delhi"}
{"name":"Sam","score":"8.9","address":"New York"}
{"name":"Michelle","score":"9.0","address":"California"}
```

My configuration file: test.config

```
input{
 file{
        path => "/Users/amit/elasticsearch/data/test.json"
        codec => json
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
        start_position => "beginning"
 }
}

filter{
    json{
        source => "message"
    }

    mutate{
        convert => { 
            "name" => "text"
            "score" => "float"
            "address" => "text"
        }
    }
}

output{
    elasticsearch{
        hosts => "localhost:9200"
        index => "test"
    }
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

I am trying to import this data into elasticsearch using logstash using the following command:

```
bin/logstash -f ../../data/test.config
```

But I get the following error message:

> **[2018-12-27T20:18:41,439][ERROR][logstash.pipeline]** Error registering
>   plugin {:pipeline_id=>"main",
>   :plugin=>"#,
>   @filter={\"name\"=>\"text\",
>   \"score\"=>\"float\", \"address\"=>\"text\"},
>   id=>\"4a292b8b637c63de89c36b730212b3c706307f5fd385080369ac0cbeac3c2d53\", enable_metric=>true, periodic_flush=>false>>", :error=>"translation
>   missing: en.logstash.agent.configuration.invalid_plugin_register",
>   :thread=>"#"}
>
> **[2018-12-27T20:18:41,452][ERROR][logstash.pipeline]** Pipeline aborted
>   due to error {:pipeline_id=>"main",
>   :exception=>#,
>   :backtrace=>["/Users/amit/elasticsearch/logstash/logstash-6.5.3/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-filter-mutate-3.3.4/lib/logstash/filters/mutate.rb:219:in
>   `block in register'", "org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1343:in`each'",
>   "/Users/amit/elasticsearch/logstash/logstash-6.5.3/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-filter-mutate-3.3.4/lib/logstash/filters/mutate.rb:217:in
>   `register'",
>   "/Users/amit/elasticsearch/logstash/logstash-6.5.3/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:242:in`
>   register_plugin'",
>   "/Users/amit/elasticsearch/logstash/logstash-6.5.3/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:253:in
>   `block in register_plugins'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1734:in`
>   each'",
>   "/Users/amit/elasticsearch/logstash/logstash-6.5.3/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:253:in
>   `register_plugins'",
>   "/Users/amit/elasticsearch/logstash/logstash-6.5.3/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:595:in`
>   maybe_setup_out_plugins'",
>   "/Users/amit/elasticsearch/logstash/logstash-6.5.3/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:263:in
>   `start_workers'",
>   "/Users/amit/elasticsearch/logstash/logstash-6.5.3/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:200:in`
>   run'",
>   "/Users/amit/elasticsearch/logstash/logstash-6.5.3/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:160:in
>   `block in start'"], :thread=>"#"}
>
> **[2018-12-27T20:18:41,474][ERROR][logstash.agent]** Failed to execute
>   action {:id=>:main,
>   :action_type=>LogStash::ConvergeResult::FailedAction, :message=>"Could
>   not execute action: PipelineAction::Create, action_result:
>   false", :backtrace=>nil}
>
> **[2018-12-27T20:18:41,705][INFO ][logstash.agent]** Successfully started
>   Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}

Also, if I remove the mutate filter from the file test.config, it works fine. But, I want to change the type of ***score*** variable to float. Is there a problem in trying to mutate the fields during parsing or I am missing something else? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-convert

Seems you cant use "text", use "name" => "string"

Comment: Hi LeBigCat, thanks. It had to be this simple solution :)
Now I tried adding a new field lastUpdated in my JSON file which will be having UNIX timestamp in milliseconds. I wish to parse this field as date and send it to elasticsearch where I would visualize this as something like this:

In JSON file : lastUpdated: 1545078074640
In Kibana data: lastUpdated: December 18th 2018, 01:51:14.640

How do I change my test.config file to achive this?

Comment: Hi Amit, if you want to index a date and use this date in kibana or any querry, elastic will have to store this date in his format, you cant change that. If you need also to visualise the date in another format (for any reason), index it in the format you want as a text (a string ;)). Hops it help

Comment: @AmitSingh To parse a date, you can use the [date filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html), which supports UNIX timestamp as a pattern.